# Using Mailjet purely as SMTP server - pros & cons?

Tags: civimail, smtp

Mailjet is undoubtedly very good at delivering emails, but the Mailjet extensions for Civi don't seem to be current & don't process bounces.  However, given this limitation, using Mailjet solely as an SMTP server without an extension works well and gets emails delivered.  Mailjet has some nice reports too. I've tested this setup and it works fine, but I'm concerned that there might be some disadvantage that I've overlooked.  Can anyone comment on this setup? Pros & Cons?  I'm using 5.13.5 with Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with a site that has used MailJet via SMTP for a number of years. I'm not aware of any issues of using it in that way.

Comment: And I assume they look at Mailjet for bounces and not at Civi?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I didn't set it up myself.